# Заполнение input из чекбокса

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть несколько чекбоксов нужно сделать так чтоб когда пользователь отмечает чекбокс то заполняется нужный инпут из value чекбокса ? кто ни будь встречал подобный скрипт ? или кто ни будь может закинуть пример ?

```js
var boxes = $("input:checkbox");
$("input:checkbox").on("change", function() {
  var theArray = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    var box = boxes[i];
    if ($(box).prop('checked')) {
      theArray[theArray.length] = $(box).val();
    }
  }
  showValues(theArray);
});
var showValues = function(array) {
  var text = "";
  if (array.length == 0) text += "Ни один чекбокс не выбран";
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    text += "Чекбокс " + array[i] + " выбран!<br />";
  }
  $(".values").html(text);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Работа с input type="checkbox"</h3>
  <span>Выберите флажки</span><br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" id="check1" value="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb2" id="check2" value="2" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb3" id="check3" value="3" />
  <div class="values">Ни один чекбокс не выбран</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Value чекбокса? True/false чтоли? В input?

Comment: Так https://jsfiddle.net/br3t/fpwhkcuq/ ?

Comment: <div class="container"><h3>Работа с input type="checkbox"</h3>
  <span>Выберите флажки</span><br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" id="check1" value="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb2" id="check2" value="2" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb3" id="check3" value="3" />
  <div class="values">Ни один чекбокс не выбран</div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script> Это код HTML а это код JS  var boxes = $("input:checkbox");
$("input:checkbox").on("change", function(){
var theArray = new Array();for (var i=0;i<boxes.length;i++) { var box = boxes[i];   if ($(box).prop('checked')) { theArray[theArray.length] = $(box).val();  }}  showValues(theArray);});var showValues = function(array) {  var text = "";  if(array.length == 0) text += "Ни один чекбокс не выбран";  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
text += "Чекбокс "+array[i]+" выбран!<br />";
   }
  $(".values").html(text);
}

Comment: Он передает в ДИВ а надо в инпут

Comment: Меняете div на `<input class="values" value="Ни один чекбокс не выбран" />`, а в коде `$(".values").val(text);`

Comment: Спасибо работает ! А как сделать чтоб когда убираете "галочку" чекбокса запись тоже исчезало

Comment: все ок работает как надо. Спасибо br3t